# Axis2 and WAS 7.0 integration

Tags: apache-axis

I am trying to integrate axis2 -1.6.2 and Websphere7 .
I followed the links provided by Andreas such as: http://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/docs/app_server.html
and I also excluded axis1.4 which was getting downloaded transitively. 
The module is 'parent-last' class loading and whole EAR , I tried both parent-first and last but I still get 
java.lang.InstantiationError: org.apache.axis2.databinding.**ADBDataSource**.....and 
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/fileupload/**FileUploadException**
though I have commons-fileupload jar and axis2-1.6.2 and axis2-adb jar.

Please post any suggestions.
FYI: I also followed this procedure :
http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?rs=0&q1=axis2&q2=technote&uid=swg21315686&loc=en_US&cs=utf-8&cc=us&lang=en
Thanks.

Comment: In the description of the issue, you should include the structure of the EAR file (in terms of EJB and Web modules and where the JARs are included).

Comment: I added the jars in pom.xml. The EAR has only 1 war which has all axis properties and the file axis2.xml. Is this what you needed?